# how to run an app with flutter-pi from a docker container

Tags: flutter, docker

I'm running a flutter app on a raspberry pi 4, I'm using [flutter-pi](https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi). Everything works fine, but I want to take it to a higher level.

I want to encapsulate the app and all flutter-pi dependencies in a docker container.

I am using the **ubuntu:jammy** image as a base, I have installed all the dependencies according to [flutter-pi](https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi).

When I run the app I get this error:

```
[locales] Warning: The system has no configured locale. The default "C" locale may or may not be supported by the app.
[keyboard] Could not load keyboard configuration from "/etc/default/keyboard". Default keyboard config will be used. load_file: No such file or directory
[flutter-pi] Could not query DRM device list: No such file or directory
```

**NOTE:** the raspberry is configured to do a console auto login and does not have a graphical interface

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a flutter-pi application and encapsulated it in a container.

What I noticed is that this error `(Could not query DRM device list: No such file or directory)` happens to me only sometimes, the configuration is always the same but sometimes I faced it and some times I didn't.

I'm assuming it is related with the host system in which the docker containers are running, because as I previously said the configuration of the container is always the same in both the working container and the not working one.

I'm attaching down below the configuration of my dockerfile (it's made of 2 dockerfiles but it's only 1 container that I'm running, the second dockerfile uses the first one which is built in emotionsrl/tower-display-base).

The display_launcher.py only runs the flutter (`flutter-pi --release ./spotlink_build`) after a few checks that are not related with the rest.

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt -y update \
    && apt -y install git \
    && apt -y install wget \
    && apt -y install build-essential

WORKDIR /TOWER_DISPLAY

# STEP 1 DIPENDENZE
RUN git clone --depth 1 \
    https://github.com/ardera/flutter-engine-binaries-for-arm.git \
    engine-binaries && cd engine-binaries && ./install.sh

# STEP 2 DIPENDENZE
ENV TZ=Europe/Rome
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt -y install cmake \
    libgl1-mesa-dev \
    libgles2-mesa-dev \
    libegl1-mesa-dev \
    libdrm-dev \
    libgbm-dev

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' apt -y install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
RUN apt -y install fontconfig \
    libsystemd-dev \
    libinput-dev \
    libudev-dev \
    libxkbcommon-dev

#STEP 3 DIPENDENZE
RUN fc-cache
###########################
# COMPILING
RUN git clone https://github.com/ardera/flutter-pi
WORKDIR /TOWER_DISPLAY/flutter-pi/build
RUN cmake ..
RUN make -j `nproc`
RUN make install
```

```
FROM emotionsrl/tower-display-base

WORKDIR /TOWER_DISPLAY

COPY spotlink_build ./spotlink_build
COPY display_launcher.py ./display_launcher.py

CMD python3 ./display_launcher.py
```

Comment: hi @davide-balducci, thanks for your answer, I did not understand your answer. In that dockerfile you are only installing the dependencies and the necessary things, but at what moment do you run the app from the container? For example, the counter app. Thank you

Comment: This is only the base (emotionrsl/tower-display-base):

`FROM emotionsrl/tower-display-base

WORKDIR /TOWER_DISPLAY

COPY spotlink_build ./spotlink_build
COPY display_launcher.py ./display_launcher.py

CMD python3 ./display_launcher.py`

Comment: Please @davide-balducci, Could you share the code in the "display_launcher.py" file? Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've downvoted the question because the answer is incomplete and doesn't answer my question. Please @davide-balducci, Could you share the code in the "display_launcher.py" file? Thank very you.

Comment: display_launcher.py only runs the flutter project that I produced after a few checks that I made that don't matter with the question.

`import yaml
import subprocess


    subprocess.Popen(
        "flutter-pi --release ./spotlink_build",
        shell=True,
    ).wait()`

What I was saying is that I also was facing that error on DRM, and it happens only sometimes but I don't know why.

Comment: ok, very well. thanks @davide-balducci